# Implement interface with the type of a subclass in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I implement the interface below in Typescript, avoiding the commented errors?

These are the classes imported from angular:

**This is base class which is defined in the interface:**

```
export declare abstract class LocationStrategy {
  abstract path(includeHash?: boolean): string;
  abstract prepareExternalUrl(internal: string): string;
  abstract pushState(state: any, title: string, url: string, queryParams: string): void;
  abstract replaceState(state: any, title: string, url: string, queryParams: string): void;
  abstract forward(): void;
  abstract back(): void;
  abstract onPopState(fn: LocationChangeListener): void;
  abstract getBaseHref(): string;
  static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<LocationStrategy, never>;
}
```

**This is the class used in the implementation of the interface**

```
export declare class PathLocationStrategy extends LocationStrategy {
  private _platformLocation;
  private _baseHref;
  constructor(_platformLocation: PlatformLocation, href?: string);
  onPopState(fn: LocationChangeListener): void;
  getBaseHref(): string;
  prepareExternalUrl(internal: string): string;
  path(includeHash?: boolean): string;
  pushState(state: any, title: string, url: string, queryParams: string): void;
  replaceState(state: any, title: string, url: string, queryParams: string): void;
  forward(): void;
  back(): void;
  static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<PathLocationStrategy,[null, { optional: true }]>;
  static ɵprov: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectableDef<PathLocationStrategy>;
}
```

My code:

I really need to provide types in the implementations, which will be used as tokens.
The `environment` constant is correct, but I need to create several similar ones, so I want to create an interface for it.

So what I need is to correctly infer the `IEnvironment` interface without modifying `locationStrategy: PathLocationStrategy` in the implementation.

```
import { LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

export interface IEnvironment {
  production: boolean;
  locationStrategy: LocationStrategy;
  // This is just a test trying to infer what the interface should look like.
  locationStrategy1: typeof LocationStrategy;
}
const environment: IEnvironment = {
  production: false,

   // Type 'typeof PathLocationStrategy' is missing the following properties from type
   // 'LocationStrategy': path, prepareExternalUrl, pushState, replaceState, and 4 more.ts(2740)
  locationStrategy: PathLocationStrategy, 

   // Type 'typeof PathLocationStrategy' is not assignable to type 'typeof LocationStrategy'.
   // Types of construct signatures are incompatible.
   // Type 'new (_platformLocation: PlatformLocation, href?: string | undefined)
   // => PathLocationStrategy' is not assignable to type 'abstract new () => LocationStrategy'.ts(2322)
  locationStrategy1: PathLocationStrategy,
};
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgGQgYwIY2BAdgZRiiwFMBzATwBo4AFLAC1U2z0OJnIrgF84AzKBBBwA5AAEMuMgFcANhigB6NMJB5RAbgCwAKD0kAHpFhxguTlH4Y0JOAEkAorgBuwIbhAkLiPXDhgQgAmMmisuABccABGEBByJFI6uv5y6Fg4BESklFHMGWzZnJTJqenh7DkUAIxRMBRgJBD8KOWZlcUUyTx6qrgAzvDebh5eFlFOru54Y-AAvL4pAcGh4VHWcv0kVH5waSztRVxR9DBMbYUcXDtL+wVZV5S1dIz5FUeUNzyaQA)

Comment: Could you please add the definitions of LocationStrategy and PathLocationStrategy?

Comment: For production field you have the set the value as false. But for other two fields, you are just specifying the class name, instead it should be an instance of PathLocationStrategy.

Comment: Unless you want to add an `angular` tag to this, can you remove dependencies on particular angular types or provide typings for them?  It looks like `locationStrategy` is supposed to be an *instance* of `LocationStrategy` but you're just putting the constructor in there (like asking for a hamburger and getting a whole restaurant).  You need something like `new LocationStrategy(...)` with proper arguments (like ordering a hamburger from the restaurant).  For `locationStrategy1` it looks like you're asking for a constructor, but I don't quite understand why, and the name isn't helpful (why `1`?)

Comment: Hi @jcalz thanks for your comments, i have added details to the question.
locationStrategy1 is just a test trying to infer what the interface should look like.

Comment: Hi @Sam thanks for your comments, i have added details to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution I found.

```
// @angular/core
export declare const Type: FunctionConstructor;

export declare interface Type<T> extends Function {
    new (...args: any[]): T;
}
```

Solution:

```
import { LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { Type } from '@angular/core';

export interface IEnvironment {
  production: boolean;
  locationStrategy: Type<LocationStrategy>;
}
```